# Тег <base> в HTML: ссылка на документ, а не на каталог. Зачем?

Tags: html

Известный тег, но тут встретил это:
[описание тега `base`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base) от разработчиков Mozzila (проект MDN)

Но вот что значит, когда атрибут тега `href` указывает не адрес каталога, а на адрес конкретного файла?
Допустим `<base href="http://www.example.com/page.html">`
Для чего это так?
Что подразумевает этот ход?
На сайтах у некоторых видел (на CMS Joomla)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Потому что на якори это тоже влияет. Было бы странно их считать от папки, а не от страницы.

> `<base href="http://thisrocks.com/app/">`
>
> При использовании `<base>` вы можете столкнуться с проблемой ссылок на внутристраничные якоря.
>
> Обычно ссылка вида `<a href="#top">Наверх</a>` оставит вас на текущей странице, но перенесет к элементу с `id="top"`, то есть она будет ссылаться на `http://thisrocks.com/app/article.html#top`.
>
> Но если вы используете тег  с заданным атрибутом href, то вы будете перенаправлены на базовый URL с добавленным к адресу сегментом `#top`, то есть `http://thisrocks.com/app/#top`.
>
> В этом случае также необходимо переопределить умолчания, заданные тегом , указав страницу, к которой относится ваш якорь, то есть `<a href="article.html#top">Наверх</a>`
>
> [Источник](http://ruseller.com/lessons.php?id=2067)

Comment: Только якори не вызывают переходов между страницами. Соответственно не важно какая база у документа (HTTP-сессии все равно не будет)

Comment: @tutankhamun, переход будет. Открой (если ты не в IE) `data:text/html,<!doctype html><title>Demo</title><base href="http://google.ru"><a href="#">Go</a>` и нажми на ссылку.

Comment: Шайтан! Посыпаю голову пеплом. +1 в репу

Answer (score 2):

То же самое и подразумевает. Просто база для относительных ссылок. Фактически такая ссылка может (или должна) указывать на адрес самого документа. Это удобно когда документ сохраняется на диск (относительные ссылки не перестают работать)